# Solving a circuit implementing a two-level unitary operation

Tags: quantum-gate, matrix-representation, circuit-construction

The circuit below implements the following two-level unitary transformation:

[image: transformation matrix]

[image: quantum circuit]

$\tilde{U}$ is a unitary matrix: $\tilde{U} = \left[\begin{matrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{matrix}\right]$

where $a, b, c, d$ are any complex numbers.

As we can see, $U$ acts non-trivially only on the states $\lvert 000 \rangle, \lvert 111 \rangle$.

How would you solve the circuit for the input state $\lvert 000 \rangle$ or $\lvert 111 \rangle$? My problem is figuring out how to deal with the state $\tilde{U}A$ in last two CNOT gates.

EDIT: to clarify what I want:

- I start with $\lvert \psi_{0} \rangle = \lvert 0, 0, 0 \rangle$
- after the first CNOT I get $\lvert \psi_{1} \rangle = \lvert 0, 0, 1 \rangle$
- after the second CNOT I get $\lvert \psi_{2} \rangle = \lvert 0, 1, 1 \rangle$
- ...

How would you write $\lvert \psi_{3} \rangle$, $\lvert \psi_{4} \rangle$, $\lvert \psi_{5} \rangle$? For this specific circuit, is it even possible to write the full steps like that?

Comment: what's the difference between white circle and black circle?

Comment: The black circle represent a control which should be 1 to be applied. A white one would require a 0.

Comment: You already said what U does through the full matrix/ circuit. Do you want to say what is after each gate individually?

Comment: @AHusain precisely, suppose you do not have the matrix representation, you only have the circuit, therefore you need to solve it.

Comment: So you have written down the matrices for each of the three types of gates in the circuit and are having trouble with the multiplication step $U=U_1 U_2 U_3 U_2 U_1$? You can use computer algebra to do that if you're having trouble doing a bunch of 8 by 8 matrix multiplications.

Comment: @AHusain yours is definitely one way to do it. Let me edit the question to be more specific.

Comment: Note: you can drop the C controls on the 2nd and 4th operations without changing the overall effect of the circuit. (Because they are each other's inverse and there is a matching control on the center operation they are conjugating.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
| \psi_3 \rangle = a | 0 1 1 \rangle + b | 1 1 1 \rangle\\
$$

Because the 1 on B and C criterion is met.

$$
| \psi_4 \rangle = a | 0 0 1 \rangle + b | 1 1 1 \rangle\\
$$

Because only the first term meets the criterion for the controls so it is the only part affected to flip the B index.

$$
| \psi_5 \rangle = a | 0 0 0 \rangle + b | 1 1 1 \rangle\\
$$

Because only the first term meets the criterion for the controls so it is the only part affected to flip the C index.